Priorização de condições Case When
Boa tarde pessoal!
Estou fazendo uma query para pegar o momento do cliente.
Minha dúvida é sobre se temos priorização dentro de uma condição case when. Por exemplo:
SELECT 
CASE WHEN EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 1
                FROM COMPRAS 
                WHERE COMPRAS.CID = CLIENTES.EMAIL
            )
            THEN 'COMPROU' 
        WHEN EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM ABANDONO           
                WHERE ABANDONO.CID = CLIENTES.CID
            ) 
            THEN 'ABANDONOU'
        WHEN EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM PESQUISA
                WHERE PESQUISA.CID = CLIENTES.CID
            ) 
            THEN 'PESQUISOU     
            ELSE 'OUTROS'
        END AS MOMENTO,
FROM CLIENTES

Gostaria de saber se um cliente existir na compra e também na pesquisa, ele entraria na primeira condição e seria atribuído o valor COMPROU ou seria atribuído o valor PESQUISOU para ele?

Sim, vale a primeira condição atendida

A resposta curta é sim, ele cai na primeira condição.
Uma resposta mais completa seria essa referência aqui do w3cschools
once a condition is true, it will stop reading and return the result

O que respauda a resposta mais curta.
